# After pointer is closed, the file cannot be deleted by using the system() command, and show the file is used by another program

Tags: c, file, pointers

After `fclose(fpointer)`, I am trying to delete that file by using `system("del text_file.txt");`, but the output is saying that "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

FILE * fpointer;

int main() {
    int times;
    char option;

    //Read the file
    if ((fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "r")) == NULL) //If this file dont exist
    {
        fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "w");//Create the file
        fprintf(fpointer, "0");
        fclose(fpointer);
        fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "r");//Reopen with reading mode
    }
    else
    {
        fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "r");
    }
    fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &times);//Save the number of note to variable
    fclose(fpointer);

    //Add 1 times when the program launch
    fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "w");
    times++;
    fprintf(fpointer, "%d", times);//Save current variable to file
    fclose(fpointer);

    printf("You have launch this program %d times!\n", times);
    printf("Do you want to reset the number?(Y/N)\n>>");
    scanf(" %c", &option);

    if (option == 'Y')
    {
        system("del file_open.txt");//delete the file
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe program is exiting now...\n");
        _getch();//Press any key to exit
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

1) Assuming that input is always correct.

2) I am trying to not replace the `file_open.txt` with `1`

Is that possible to delete the file by using `system("del text_file.txt")` ?

Edit: Some mistakes is fixed.

Edit:

I tried to use `remove()` in my code, this is the part that I modified:

```
if (option == 'Y')
    {
        int status;
        char file_name[] = "file_open.txt";
        status = remove(file_name);//delete the file
        if (status == 0)
        {
            printf("%s file deleted successfully.\n", file_name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unable to delete the file\n");
            perror("Following error occurred");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe program is exiting now...\n");
        _getch();//Press any key to exit
        exit(0);
    }
```

The problem solved by removing `fopen(fpointer)`, thanks.

Comment: you're opening it *twice* if it did exist. remove the `fopen` from the `else` branch. You don't need `system("del")` to remove the file either, as `remove` exists as a function in the C standard library.

Comment: This is a Windows program (see `_getch()`)? If so I can't reproduce the problem although I first fixed three MSVC compiler warnings. Two extra `;` and a missing `#include <conio.h>`. Are you sure you don't have `file_open.txt` open in a text editor? EDIT: I reproduce the problem after saying N the first time and running the program again. See above comment.

Comment: You have made changes to the code, but Stackoverflow isn't a step-by-step code improvement or tutorial site. If you find a new problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for you all to comment, I go search the tutorial for `remove()`, and it works perfectly. And the problem which file cannot be deleted after second times launch have been solve by delete the second `fopen(fpointer)` .

Comment: For the first comment: It really fixes my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else block in :

```
//Read the file
if ((fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "r")) == NULL) //If this file dont exist
{
    ...
}
else
{
    fpointer = fopen("file_open.txt", "r");
}
```

Will open the file a second time (or may fail to open it in some cases), but it will replace `fpointer`, so you are no longer able to close the first opening.  So you opened the file twice, but only closed one, and have lost the handle necessary to close the first by overwriting it.  The else-block should be removed.

Apart from that, you would do better to use `remove()` to delete a file. `system()` will start an entire command shell session just to perform the task, so is a rather heavyweight solution.

Comment: I think this is what I don't understand at the first place, but I understood after you explained to me. My code works perfectly now, thanks.